# after navigate() method web page is stopped working in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After navigation on page, 
    `driver.navigate().to("http://");`

nothing is working, page is transferred but it stops execution. If we go to browser and manually refresh it, then it is executing next step.

No error or exception, But still its stop working after navigation.

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

also not calling as on next step. It holds everything.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("Why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Not getting exception, Debugging also retrieving only timeout log. No such description as outcome.

Comment: It found only for Chrome Browser,

Comment: How many driver.navigate() calls are you making? Is your very first call to navigate also seeing the same problem?

Comment: Before to execute it, single time its already used.

Comment: @IshitaShah I am facing same problem. Did you figure out the solution?

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani Yes, We need to wait properly for Web page to load until its gets completely finished. You can try by Thread.sleep() or Explicit Wait. And if its gets work you may implement JSwaiter methodology. (https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-wait-javascript-angular-ajax/)

Comment: @IshitaShah Thanks. Actually in my case we upgrade the chrome version and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets to load properly by Javascript, Jquery, and Angular. Until page get not loaded fully, it will be under downstage and can't iterate to next line of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just navigate to a certain web page then the following code will work unlimited times:

```
driver.get("__URL__")
```

and then in order to refresh you write:

```
driver.refresh()
```

Comment: I have tried with driver.get() and driver.navigate() both. But none is working.

Comment: and you have tried to just use one of the kinds in your whole script?

Comment: Using both, according to preferences.